# Deeplabv3 not predicting classes

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, mobilenet, deeplab

I'm trying to train deeplabv3 model with mobilenetv3_small_seg architecture. I trained the model but the predictions I get is a complete blank mask with no class predictions. Steps I followed for training are:

1. Cloned official repository in Google Colab.
2. I prepared dataset with only one class (segmenting lips in a face). I followed Pascal VOC12 dataset format. I created RGB masks (0, 255, 0) with white boundaries around it (255, 255, 255) and black background (0, 0, 0) as shown below.

   [image: RGB mask]
   [image: RGB mask]
3. I then converted the RGB mask into single channel png (8 bit) with background:0, forground:1 and boundaries:255 with the help of this [script](https://gist.github.com/beerensahu/3aee46ef4552a2f5e312e072415194e3#file-label_pqr-py) as shown below:

   [image: RGB mask]
   [image: color map removed]
4. I then successfully converted the dataset into tfrecord by modifying this [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/download_and_convert_voc2012.sh).
5. Then I added my dataset description in the data_generator.py with ignore_label=255 and num_classes=2.
6. Finally I started training with the following command:

   ```
    !python train.py \
        --logtostderr \
        --training_number_of_steps=10000 \
        --train_split="val" \
        --model_variant="mobilenet_v3_small_seg" \
        --decoder_output_stride=16 \
        --train_crop_size="256,256" \
        --train_batch_size=16 \
        --dataset="pqr" \
        --save_interval_secs=600 \
        --save_summaries_secs=300 \
        --save_summaries_images=True \
        --log_steps=200 \
        --train_logdir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR} \
        --dataset_dir=${PATH_TO_DATASET}
   ```
7. After when training is complete, I tested the model with several different images. The output of the model is (256, 256) array with all values equals to 0. Not a single values I get 1 or anything else.

I'm new to machine learning. I want to know that

1. what's wrong with my process? I watched many tutorials but I couldn't find the answer.
2. Is there anything wrong with my dataset? The dataset contained total of 2000 images.
3. I couldn't find the pretrained weights for mobilenetv3_small. If anybody knows, kindly share it so I can do the transfer learning.
4. I set the number of classes to 2 (background and foreground). Is that right?

Comment: Are you just passing in the black and white image with the lips segmented to the model?

Comment: I've put all original images in JPEGImages folder and the segmented masks in SegmentationClassRaw folder. The convert.sh script has those two paths to convert the data into tfrecords.

Comment: Test with: --base_learning_rate=0.125

Comment: hi @NoumanAhsan, did you manage to solve your problem and could please share some details?